# How to cache locally in browser when s-maxage > max-age

Tags: caching, proxy, http-headers, cache-control

**In short:**

Let’s say `s-maxage` is one day and `max-age` is one hour. The proxy cache will keep a resource for a day, but after a few hours the `Age` header will be more than one hour. The browser sees the resource is older than one hour and won’t cache it locally. How to cache it locally in the browser regardless?

---

I'm trying to combine `Cache-Control: max-age` and `s-maxage` with sensible values.
But setting `s-maxage > max-age` doesn't seem to make sense.
Eventually the browser will always revalidate resources and will skip local browser cache, because resources received from proxy cache will immediately be stale (`Age > max-age`).

**Goals:**

- Reduce load on origin: set long TTL at edge cache (`s-maxage`), this can be purged when necessary.
- Speed up browser session: set small cache on browser (`max-age`).

**Problem:**

A resource stays in proxy cache for a long time (`s-maxage`), while its `Age` increases (time since fetch from origin).
Eventually the `Age` of the resource in cache will be larger than `max-age`.
When that happens the browser will revalidate every time it needs a resource, since the resource is stale on every request.

For example: `Cache-Control: max-age=60, s-maxage=86400`.
The browser should keep a resource for 60 seconds. The proxy cache keeps a resource for a day.

```
t=0
browser: need resource
proxy cache: fetch resource from origin
-> cache returns fresh resource with Age: 0 / Cache-Control: "max-age=60, s-max-age=86400"

t=30
browser: locally cached resource is still fresh: Age (0+30) < max-age (60)

t=70
browser: local cache is stale: Age (0+70) > max-age (60) -> revalidate
proxy cache: cached resource is still fresh: Age (70) < s-maxage (86400)
-> cache returns resource with Age: 70, Cache-Control: "max-age=60, s-maxage=86400"
```

The cache returned a resource with an `Age (70)` that is larger than `max-age (60)`.
From now on every time the browser wants the resource it will be stale locally and needs revalidation.

```
t=75
browser: local cache is stale: Age (70+5) > max-age (60) -> revalidate
proxy cache: cached resource is still fresh: Age (75) < s-maxage (86400)
-> cache returns resource with Age: 75 / Cache-Control: "max-age=60, s-max-age=86400"
```

This means that if a resource is in proxy cache for longer than `max-age` the browser will *always* revalidate.
The `max-age` value is only useful for `max-age` seconds after getting a fresh resource from origin.

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. How can I adjust this such that the browser will always cache a resource for 60s after requesting it, even if that received resource has been in proxy cache for a long time? (Or is this bad practice?)

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to do #2 to speed up a browser session for a user. When a user accesses page A, then page B, then again page A ideally the browser shouldn't need to revalidate A, because it has been accessed just a minute ago. I don't care that the original resource for A has been generated a long time ago due to `s-maxage`.

Comment: What's strange to me is that combining `max-age` and `s-maxage` doesn't seem to be useful in practice, unless `max-age = 0` (always revalidate) or `max-age > s-maxage` (longer local cache).

Comment: Because the proxy cache is under my control and can be purged whenever necessary. The browser cache cannot be cleared by me. So when I update resources I can clear the proxy cache. If the browser cache is small the resources will be available shortly to the end user and they don't have to wait a day (or force refresh). Appreciate your insights!

Comment: Actually, the proxy caches aren't under your control! You may be thinking of one particular proxy cache (some CDN or edge server?), but there may be others that you know nothing about. The purpose of these headers is to communicate with arbitrary HTTP actors, so if your headers don't make sense for other proxy caches then I'd say they're incorrect. If you have control over a particular proxy cache then presumably you also have the ability to control it's caching with out-of-protocol means other than `s-maxage`. (For example, Cloudfront has various settings, `Minimum TTL` etc.)

Comment: Ah yes, that's correct of course! A custom `TTL` would help with purging, but I'm not sure how a custom `TTL` setting would help with the original problem, i.e. `max-age: 60` and `TTL: 86400` — after 60 seconds the browser will always revalidate as the `Age` of the resource in cache still increases. `TTL` and `s-maxage` have essentially the same behaviour (except `TTL` won't propagate to other caches). I guess the only way to do this is if I have control over the `Age`/`Date` headers and adjust those to `0`/`now`?

Comment: Yes, and I think that's the crux of the issue. Your scheme only makes sense when you have control of the cache and can invalidate it at will, meaning that it's more like an origin server than a proxy cache as described in the standards. So, in the same way that the CDN exposes settings that allow you to control the TTL, it could also expose settings to allow you to, say, reset the Age when you serve the file. As to whether that's actually possible with Cloudfront or something else, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your help! If you're interested in formulating this as an answer I'll happily accept it. Whether it's possible to adjust those headers is indeed an implementation detail of the specific cache and beyond the scope here :) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setting `s-maxage > max-age` doesn't seem to make sense.***

Your analysis looks correct, and I think I agree. Specifically, given a particular value of `s-maxage` it’s hard to see any reason why you’d want to use a smaller `max-age`, since that will result in pointless conditional validation requests.

Note that there are reasonable use cases for setting `max-age > s-maxage`, so it still makes sense for the protocol to define these as two separate directives.

***How can I force the browser to cache a resource for a specific amount of time after receiving it, regardless of its freshness (as indicated by the `Age` header)?***

HTTP caching is based on the age of the resource, not when a response happened to be received. So there’s no way to force the user’s browser or the proxy cache to do this.

***But my cache plan is perfectly reasonable: I want to set `max-age` to a small value that accurately represents the degree of staleness I can tolerate, but set `s-maxage` to a long value and simply invalidate the proxy cache when the resource changes. Why won’t the HTTP specification support that?***

The fundamental issue here is that your—indeed, perfectly reasonable—cache scheme relies on having control over the proxy cache (to force invalidation), whereas the internet architecture defined by HTTP is based on independent actors that the origin server doesn't have control over. What you’re describing as a proxy cache is better thought of as a *managed cache*. MDN has a [useful discussion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#types_of_caches) of this:

> Shared caches can be further sub-classified into **proxy caches** and **managed caches**.... Managed caches are **explicitly deployed by service developers** to offload the origin server and to deliver content efficiently....
>
> In most cases, you can control the [managed] cache's behavior through the `Cache-Control` header and **your own configuration files or dashboards**. For example, the HTTP Caching specification essentially does not define a way to explicitly delete a cache—but with a managed cache, the stored response can be deleted at any time through dashboard operations, API calls, restarts, and so on. That allows for a more proactive caching strategy.

So if you’re using a managed cache (Cloudfront, etc.) you don’t need to use `s-maxage` at all to manage the cache. You can directly control the settings outside of the HTTP protocol.

***Even if I use settings to control the managed cache retention period, I still face the issue of the `Age` header forcing the browser to revalidate.***

In the same way that the managed cache exposes TTL settings, it could also expose the ability to send a fresh `Age` header on each response. Whether any particular managed cache solution does that, I don’t know.